# iPhone Game Programming: Multiple UIImageViews in a UIViewController or UIImages in a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

so just a general question on what people think is the most efficient method for programming a game. My game will have a number of images moving all over the screen and rotating, changing, etc.
The two options I see for a construction are:

1. Create 1 UIViewController and add to it a bunch of UIImageViews
   at runtime, and then move these UIImageViews around programatically
2. Create a UIVIewController and add to it a sublclass of UIView,
       say GameView. Then, add an array of objects (which contains data
       like UIImage and location) to GameView, and override the drawRect
       method of GameView to draw these objects.

My question is, which one seems like it would put the least strain on the device? Is it bad to have a large number of UIImageViews moving around, because it seems like they have to remember a lot more data than just the UIImage and location, which is pretty much all I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the UIImages in the UIView.  It'll be a lot lighter-weight, and it makes more sense.  For best performance, though, you're going to need to switch to OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `UIImageView` approach. Apple optimized `UIImageView` for drawing and you are circumventing that if you use the `drawRect:` approach.

You could also take a look at `CALayer` for another lightweight approach if you dont need touch events.

Comment: Yes, but I would still be using apples drawImageAtPoint method, which should be pretty well optomized, right? Also, isn't it bad to be continually allocating and releasing a large number of UIImageViews, in terms of memory?